# how to replace string at specific index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
    code     bucket
    0        08:30:00-9:00:00
    1        10:00:00-11:00:00
    2        12:00:00-13:00:00
```

I want to replace 7th character `0` with `1`, my desired dataframe is

```
   code     bucket
    0       08:30:01-9:00:00
    1       10:00:01-11:00:00
    2       12:00:01-13:00:00
```

How to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Use indexing with `str`:

```
df['bucket'] = df['bucket'].str[:7] + '1' + df['bucket'].str[8:]
```

Or `list comprehension`:

```
df['bucket'] = [x[:7] + '1' + x[8:] for x in df['bucket']]
```

---

```
print (df)
   code             bucket
0     0   08:30:01-9:00:00
1     1  10:00:01-11:00:00
2     2  12:00:01-13:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid string operations where possible

You lose a considerable amount of functionality by working with strings only. While this may be a one-off operation, you will find that repeated string manipulations will quickly become expensive in terms of time and memory efficiency.

### Use `pd.to_datetime` instead

You can add additional series to your dataframe with `datetime` objects. Below is an example which, in addition, creates an `object` dtype series in the format you desire.

```
# split by '-' into 2 series
dfs = df.pop('bucket').str.split('-', expand=True)

# convert to datetime
dfs = dfs.apply(pd.to_datetime, axis=1)

# add 1s to first series
dfs[0] = dfs[0] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)

# create object series from 2 times
form = '%H:%M:%S'
dfs[2] = dfs[0].dt.strftime(form) + '-' + dfs[1].dt.strftime(form)

# join to original dataframe
res = df.join(dfs)

print(res)

   code                   0                   1                  2
0     0 2018-10-02 08:30:01 2018-10-02 09:00:00  08:30:01-09:00:00
1     1 2018-10-02 10:00:01 2018-10-02 11:00:00  10:00:01-11:00:00
2     2 2018-10-02 12:00:01 2018-10-02 13:00:00  12:00:01-13:00:00
```